# Looking for best practice to dynamically compose functions in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to write Scala code to get list of functions from a client code and compose it using chained approach and finally apply the composed function and i am able to make it.. But i feel like i am not doing it in a functional way since i am declaring a function variable with "var" in Test.scala(below) and keep composing functions on top of it. I believe there should be a better approach and any guidance and suggestion would help me

Test.scala

```
case class Test(val int: Int){
  private final var function : Int => Int = (i: Int) => i
  def composeFunction( f: Int => Int)   : this.type = {
   function = function.andThen(f);
        this;
    }
  def applyFunction : Int = {
        function(int)
    }
}
```

Client Code: Main.scala

```
val c = new Test(6)
  .composeFunction((i: Int) => i *2)
  .composeFunction((i: Int) => i *4)
  .composeFunction((i: Int) => i *6)
  .applyFunction
```

Comment: I declared the function with name "function" in Test.scala with a default behavior ((i:Int) => i) because if the client does not call "composeFunction", then "function" should output the input value as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result by chaining only one function

```
case class Test(int: Int){
   def applyFunction(f: Int => Int): Test = {
   this.copy(f(int))
   }
}

// test
val c = Test(6)
.applyFunction((i: Int) => i * 2)
.applyFunction((i: Int) => i * 4)
.applyFunction((i: Int) => i * 6)
.int

println(c)
```

output:

```
288
```

Answer (score 4):

```
val c = Some(6)
  .map((i: Int) => i *2)
  .map((i: Int) => i *4)
  .map((i: Int) => i *6)
  .get
```

of use cats library if you need lazy evaluation

```
val lazyEval = Eval.later(6)
  .map((i: Int) => i *2)
  .map((i: Int) => i *4)
  .map((i: Int) => i *6)
  .value
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar functional composition can be achieved by repeated application of [`andThen`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html#andThen[A](g:R=%3EA):T1=%3EA) like so:

```
val c = ((i: Int) => i * 2) andThen ((i: Int) => i * 4) andThen ((i: Int) => i * 6)
c(6) // res0: Int = 288
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid mutations the best *(only?)* way, is to create a modified copy of the data you want to mutate.
For example

```
final case class Test(int: Int, function: Int => Int = identity){
  def composeFunction(f: Int => Int): Test =
    this.copy(function = this.function.andThen(f))

  def applyFunction: Int =
    function(this.int)
}

val c = Test(6)
  .composeFunction(i => i * 2)
  .composeFunction(i => i * 4)
  .composeFunction(i => i * 6)
  .applyFunction // 288.
```

However, being honest, this design seems odd to me.
Maybe, would not be better to have a list of functions, reduce it using andThen and finally applying the resulting function?

Comment: Having it as List was my first option but i wanted to preserve the order of functions as is present in client code.. I am afraid having the functions in the list would change the order.. ListBuffers preserves order?

Comment: The immutable `List` in **Scala** preserves order, the mutable `ListBuffer` also does preserve order _(specially since under the hood a `ListBuffer` are two immutable `Lists`)_. So yes, you should not worry about it.